# Disk0(C:) is jumping from 1-5% usage to 90-100% usage in Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, resource-usage

I looked at advice on other parts of the internet, and they told me to run "eventvwr.exe" through the usage of the Win+R run command. When I tried to do this it came up with an error that said "C:/WINDOWS/system32/eventvwr.exe The service cannot accept control messages at this time" and I do not know what to do! I think I might have a virus because every time I try to update windows it tells me that there was an error and that it is reverting said updates. I do not know very much about computers so somebody, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Do a Full Scan with Windows 10 Windows Defender. Open the Windows Defender screen (Start, Settings, Windows Security ad then on the right side, select Virus and Threat Protection.

Open that, and prepare to do a Full Scan (Scan Options).

Notice that an Option under Scan Options is Microsoft Defender Offline Scan.

You can do the Offline Scan after the Full Scan. The Offline Scan can quarantine viruses that WD cannot quarantine when Online.

Do both as I described and you can get rid of almost all viruses.

After doing this you should be able to update.

**Follow up:**  Given the state of the machine and your comments, you may be best at this point to do a Windows 10 Reset.

Start, Settings, Update and Security, Recovery, and then Reset this PC. Normally that will keep data, but be sure to back up anyway.

If you cannot get Reset started or going, use the Microsoft Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Make a bootable Windows 10 USB install key and use that. Be certain to back up first.

Comment: ok so, after I typed the original post I got 3 popups that said (unprompted from me, I was AFK) "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe The service cannot accept control messages at this time" I am very scared

Comment: I think I might be fucked, lol

Comment: task manager has a similar popup when I try to open it, is it the scan? or am I super-fucked?

Comment: You can do a Windows Reset. Start, Settings, Update and Security, Recovery, Reset this PC.  Normally your data is kept but back up anyway.

Comment: I click "Get started" and the settings window stops responding to clicks, uh oh spaghetti-os

Comment: Use the Microsoft Media Creation Link to make a USB Key.  You can reinstall Windows with this. Be certain to back up.